# Is it possible to perform put-redirect-get?

Tags: rest, http, submit, put

I know PRG pattern (Post- redirect- Get). can we perform same thing in case of PUT operation(put-redirect-get).

Comment: This quiestion I have asked for same purpose : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120501/405-error-code-while-calling-from-jersey-rest-client

Comment: Please refer this question:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120501/405-error-code-while-calling-from-jersey-rest-client ----  Refer this link for nerrowing down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point of having a Put-Redirect-Get. PUT already target the endpoint of the resource that is being replace.

The purpose of PRG is to avoid duplication which should never happen with PUT.

Comment: However, if I want to perform the operation, is ther any way to perform it?

Comment: Why do you want to redirect the client? It give the filling that you are not using PUT properly.